# What is the difference between terms invoke, delegate and dispatch in Java (UML)

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

So the question what is the difference between terms invoke, delegate and dispatch in Java (UML). When I am reading core J2EE patterns the authors use these terms. That's why I want to know exactly the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, UML doesn't specifically provide definitions of the above 3 terms. The way I understand them is this:

- 'Invoke' is simply sending of a message from object A to object B (invoking a method). States nothing about the purpose of that message
- 'Delegate' is when object A uses object B to fulfill some of its responsibilities.

Something like this:

```
class FlyingCar extends Car {
  private Car regularCarDelegate;

  void takeOff() {
    // logic
  }
  @Override void accelerate() {
    // delegate to the regular car's accelerate()
    regularCarDelegate.accelerate();
  }
}
```

- 'Dispatch' usually has concurrency implications. It's when your code dispatches an asynchronous worker to achieve some task while it's busy doing other things:

Say,

```
void updateContactList() {
  // dispatch
  Future<ContactList> contacts = backend.fetchContacts();
  // draw the spinner animation, disable some UI buttons etc.
}
```